# How to synthesize getter and setter for C-array on obj-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I have an ObjC object defined as follows

```
@interface Fruit : NSObject
{
    int fruitsinbranch[4];
}
@property (readonly) int fruitsinbranch[4];
@end
```

And then in the implementations I have the usual

```
@synthesize fruitsinbranch[4];
```

It does not work. What's the right way of doing it?

(And no, I am not asking for other ways to do stuff, like NSArray etc... I want an answer to the question I posed).

UPDATE: my solution is lame but it works. I created the method

```
-(int) fruitsinbranch:(int) i
```

That gave a solution close enough to what I wanted.

Comment: I assume you're not actually missing that 'y' in @property?

Comment: I swear my compiler can fill in missing letters :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can get is to use an `int*` property and not synthesize the getter:

```
 @interface Fruit : NSObject {
     int fruitsinbranch[4];
 }
 @property (readonly) int* fruitsinbranch;
 - (int *)fruitsinbranch { return fruitsinbranch; }
```

Comment: No, no, you shouldn't give him the alternative. He wanted an answer to the question he posted! :)

Comment: @Yuji: Hey, i didn't throw an `NSArray` in :) Without alternative we can only say *"no way"*.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't meaningful to specify a setter for a C array — there isn't even such a concept as "setting an array" in C. You can initialize the array, and you can access its elements, but you cannot set the array itself.

As for a getter, I can't think of any reason it *couldn't* work, but the runtime just doesn't support C arrays as properties. It just wasn't built in — probably because arrays don't really work like other types in C, such as the previously mentioned fact that there is no such thing as *setting* them.

The closest you can get is to specify a readonly `int*` property that you malloc in your initializer.

Comment: Hm, what would a hypothetical synthesized getter do as pass-by-value doesn't work? Decay to a pointer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking — it would have to decay to a pointer, but that would be consistent with how any function returning an array works.

Comment: Can we write a Objective-C method which returns an `int[4]`, to start with?

Comment: @Yuji: No, as you can't pass them by value and decay-to-pointer is not in the language for return types. You can only return pointers or e.g. a pointer-to-array.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not supported by Objective-C to have an C-array-valued property.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `readonly` and then asking it to synthesize a setter and getter (specifically the setter) doesn't make sense, though it should work. And according to this [objective c property document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW25), you'll at least get a compiler warning when explicitly setting a setter on an object that is readonly.

Perhaps you could try explicitly setting them with `setter=` and `getter=`? I know this defies your original question, but you might raise an error if your issue is somewhere else.